# How to get list of tweets while using Omni Auth authentication? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, twitter

I ve been trying to get list of tweets while using OmniAuth authentication.
After a user is authorized using Omni auth, i passed the oauth_token and secret to OAuth::AccessToken instance.

and when i try to get the tweets using the below code

```
 
      response = access_token.request(:get, "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=10&page=2")
```

i get only 200OK when i print the response in text format.

what am i doing wrong? Please suggest.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request return a Faraday::Response. If you want the content of this request call the #body method

```
p response.body
```

Comment: When i use response.body, the output is "[]", seems to be empty